# how to run multiple unix command consecutively in single runtime in java

Tags: java, unix, process

I have a requirement to execute multiple Unix commands consecutively in a single runtime in the Java environment.

Let me describe you how many commands it would be below:

```
1. `sudo user`
2. `cd 'specified directory'`
3. `chmod -R 777` [to a directory under path specified in step 2.]
```

I need something like this mentioned below:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(1 and 2 and 3);
p.waitFor();
p.destroy();
```

Please suggest me how should I approach?

Comment: `sh -c "sudo sh -c \"cmd1; cmd2\""` should work

Comment: If that `sudo` is going to require a password, there is no way to do what you want in Java, short of writing native code.

Comment: no, for my case sudo does not need any password. Only user name.

Comment: You want the cynic to run in the given directory as the given user?